# Python serial read is extremely slow, how to speed up?

Tags: python, performance

I'm using the following code to communicate with a Digital Multi Meter (DMM).
It works ok. I can send commands and read results.
I don't use readline because I read binary data.

**The problem:**

The problem is that **it is very very slow**.
Same code written in Ruby is much faster.
When it takes 30 sec in python, it takes 2 or 3 sec in ruby (using same speed).
So it's not a hardware issue.
The only difference between Ruby code and Python is that in Python I use inWaiting() for reading all characters available. In Ruby, read() function reads all of them and not just one.

**The code:**

Here's the code:
In read_retry function I check how many characters I have to read.
I read them, and then call data_is_ok function to check if it's finished or not.
As you can see, there are '\r' embedded in the data returned.
Reading is finished when the last character is '\r' (no more data available).
So there's a loop to read numerous chunks.

```
import serial
[...]

def data_is_ok(data):
  # No status code yet
  if len(data) < 2: return False

  # Non-OK status
  if len(data) == 2 and data[0] != "0" and data[1] == "\r": return True

  # Non-OK status with extra data on end
  if len(data) > 2 and data[0] != "0":
    raise ValueError('Error parsing status from meter (Non-OK status with extra data on end)')

  # We should now be in OK state
  if data[0] != "0" or data[1] != "\r":
    raise ValueError('Error parsing status from meter (status:%c size:%d)' % (data[0], len(data)))

  return len(data) >= 4 and data[-1] == "\r"

def read_retry():
  retry_count = 0
  data = ""

  while retry_count < 500 and not data_is_ok(data):
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    data += ser.read(bytesToRead)
    if data_is_ok(data): return data
    time.sleep (0.001)
    retry_count += 1
  raise ValueError('Error parsing status from meter:  %c %d %r %r' % (data[0],len(data),data[1] == '\r', data[-1] == '\r'))

[...]

# Serial port settings
try:
  ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/cu.usbserial-AK05FTGH', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=5, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
except serial.serialutil.SerialException, err:
  print "Serial Port /dev/cu.usbserial-AK05FTGH doesn't respond"
  print err
  sys.exit()

[...]

ser.write(cmd+'\r')
data = read_retry()
```

I have used cProfile profiler. Most of the time is spent in time.sleep

Here's an extract:

```
         363096 function calls (363085 primitive calls) in 28.821 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 127 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    19050   25.245    0.001   25.245    0.001 {time.sleep}
        1    1.502    1.502    1.502    1.502 {posix.open}
```

The question:
Is it possible to make the code faster ?

Comment: Maybe remove sleep?

Comment: I tried it. In that case I need to remove the limit of 500 too, otherwise it stops.  But duration is the same, and cpu grows to 100%

Comment: Stop using inWaiting.  Try read(100000).

Comment: I tried it. It hanged, probably waiting for all that characters. So I lowered timeout to "0". It worked then but duration is the same ~28 sec

Comment: Yes, the code needs improvement, but as the very first thing I would add a debug print statement (e.g. with hexdump) after the `read` to see the data as they arrive and when they arrive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things you can do.

You shouldn't need `time.sleep()`. If you know you only want 2 bytes then do `ser.read(2)` and if you want to limit the wait time `ser.timeout = 0.01`
**EDIT** unless you are in a separate thread. Python threads are greedy. I/O operations release the thread so the main thread can run. However, in your case you are always reading the data that is in the buffer `ser.read(ser.inWaiting())`. I've found that you need to force the serial port to wait on I/O `ser.read(ser.inWaiting() + 32)`. Just make sure you also have a timeout, so you aren't waiting for the I/O forever. Also your current timeout is 5 seconds which is a long time to wait. **end edit**

You might be able to use readline `ser.readline()` this may only read to '\r\n'. I'm not sure.

If you are on Python3 then `ser.read()` returns bytes, so any comparison will be false. `data[0] == '0'` would need to be `data[0:1] == b'0'`

The other thing to do is to run the code through the debugger to make sure you are getting the data you are expecting. It is possible that a string comparison or something is wrong which would make you loop a bunch of times needlessly.

Comment: I don't know the number of bytes that will be returned, it's unpredictable. I have tried with ser.read(ser.inWaiting() + 32) and timeout = 0.01, it takes more time ~39 sec.  readline reads to '\r' and I read binary data, so CR can be embedded but meaning something else. I use Python 2.7. But thanks for these advices

Comment: I advise using a debugger to go through the data step by step. I would change your time out to be a very small timeout and I would just loop with `data += ser.read(2)` since the length of 2 is one of the requirements. I would also print all of the data read in by the serial port using `repr(data)`. In addition the while loop does Not need `data_is_ok` as a conditional because you are already checking the data in the if statement, so you are doing the same work twice.

Comment: That's right. Adding debugging showed the Ruby script and the Python one don't go through the same loops. Many more work is done in the Python side. The read and the sleep functions are not involved at all. Now I have to see what's going wrong in my script. Thanks.

Comment: ser.readline() is really slow here. I timed `send-receive` round trip of 2 bytes info, and each cycle costs around 1s in pySerial... Seems to be a pySerial issue?

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same problem that pySerial library exhibit very slow reading when using serial.readline method.

I am running Windows 7 and have tried different versions of pySerial, from 2.7 to 3.4.

Let me demonstrate my concern. A transmitter transmits new bunch of data each 0.02s with baud rate = 115200.

If I execute following

```
import serial

if __name__ == '__main__':

    serial_port = serial.Serial('COM26', 115200)   

    while(True):            
        print(serial_port.is_open)
        serial_port.readline()        
        print(serial_port.in_waiting)
```

I see the number of bytes in buffer is growing. Writing to buffer is faster than reading.

**Solution** to this problem is shown in following snippet that one must use serial.read method and read all buffered bytes at once. If I execute this

```
import serial

if __name__ == '__main__':

    serial_port = serial.Serial('COM26', 115200)

    while(True):        
        print(serial_port.is_open)
        serial_port.read(serial_port.in_waiting)                   
        print(serial_port.in_waiting)
```

then I see that serial_port.read(serial_port.in_waiting) can read very fast and it avoids the problem with accumulation of bytes in buffer.

I am fine with the solution for now but maybe somebody can explain why it behaves this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in read_retry() try using a timeout and not retry count

```
import time

def read_retry():
  timeout = 500 * 0.001
  data = ""
  tic = time.time()
  while toc - tic < timeout and not data_is_ok(data):
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    data += ser.read(bytesToRead)
    if data_is_ok(data): return data
    toc = time.time()
  raise ValueError('Error parsing status from meter:  %c %d %r %r' % (data[0],len(data),data[1] == '\r', data[-1] == '\r'))
```

Comment: I tried it. I needed to add "toc = time.time()" before the while loop.  It works but it takes ~29 sec too. I can't understand why on the same machine Ruby code is 10 times faster